# Application started to give black sceen

Tags: java, android, xml

My application is correct, when I rebooting and I did "Run" it gave me in the console:

```
[2014-04-18 07:35:17 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2014-04-18 07:35:18 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2014-04-18 07:35:34 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:EOF
[2014-04-18 07:35:35 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2014-04-18 07:35:37 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 2
[2014-04-18 07:35:40 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 3
[2014-04-18 07:35:42 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 4
[2014-04-18 07:35:44 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 5
[2014-04-18 07:35:46 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 6
[2014-04-18 07:35:48 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 7
[2014-04-18 07:35:50 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 8
[2014-04-18 07:35:52 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 9
[2014-04-18 07:35:54 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 10
[2014-04-18 07:35:56 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 11
```

Does anyone know why? besides, it started to give me a black screen

Comment: DDMS, Look for Devices-->View Menu-->Reset adb.

Comment: I figured my DDMS is empty, when I right click on it, it gives me close, what should I add? Or where?